# Deriving a template class from a non-template base

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to do have Derived derive from Base:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {};
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived::Derived()
    {

    }
};
```

This gives me the following error:

> error C3254: 'Derived':
> class contains explicit override '{ctor}' but does not derive from an
> interface that contains the function declaration
>
> note: see reference to
> class template instantiation 'Derived' being compiled
>
> error C3244:
> 'Derived::Derived(void)': this method was introduced by 'Unknown>'
> not by 'Base'

I'm totally new to templates, what simple steps am I missing? This seems like a pretty basic thing.

Comment: you get similar error for this code as you would get without the template, even without the inheritance. Btw I am a bit puzzled by the first part of the error message, is this really the code that procudes that error message?

Comment: yep. authentic error from the exact code

Comment: which compiler? Dont get me wrong, I am curious, not complaining ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 VS PRO 2017 15.9.11

Comment: funny how a simple typo can lead to such a confusing error message. fwiw [gccs output is probably a bit more helpful](https://godbolt.org/z/jROXx2)

Comment: Be careful when `Base` is a template itself and depends on `T`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to omit the "Derived::" prefix. You would only use it to refer to a symbol that was inherited, or injected into the namespace of the class Derived. So the only prefix that makes sense is "Base::" here. It has nothing to do with templates.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {};
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() {}
};
```

See a working [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce17f1adeb2c6c7d).

Comment: d'oh. ok, that was a very stupid oversight. Talk about a useless diagnostic output from the compiler.
But thanks!

Comment: @Jeffrey Or accept the answer so others can be helped.

Comment: Answered my question - it's a shame that the actual question isn't more general, as I initially passed over it as I'm not using templates. As you said, the issue is nothing to do with templates.